# Connecting Office 356 GCC subscription to MAG OMS

Tags: office365, azure-gov

Does the Office 365 Log Analytics (aka OMS) solution exist in Microsoft Azure Government enabling you to connect an Office 365 GCC subscription?

Answer (score 0):

**The Office 365 OMS solution does exist in Azure Government and supports connecting to both Office 365 and Office 365 GCC Moderate.**

Pulling data from Office 365 GCC High and Office DoD is not supported yet.
If you'd like to see that, please request it via the [Azure Government feedback forum](https://aka.ms/azuregovfeedback).

See the [Log Analytics variances for Azure Government](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-government/documentation-government-services-monitoringandmanagement#log-analytics) for more information.